# How to play video from m3u8 (HLS)

Tags: pixi.js

I downloaded https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/video.js and of course it worked fine. I'd like to play an m3u8 though, such as https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8. I tried modifying the texture creation in a few different ways:

```
const texture = PIXI.Texture.from('https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8');
const texture = PIXI.VideoBaseTexture.fromUrl('https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8');
const texture = PIXI.VideoBaseTexture.fromUrl({ src: 'https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8', mime: 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl' });
```

None of these worked though (using Chrome in Windows), so how exactly should I modify the sample program to get it to play this sample m3u8?

Answer (score -1):

I was having same problem. I was unable to play some m3u8 urls using HTML's simple video tag.

Hence, I found below js which worked fine with my code.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<!-- Or if you want a more recent canary version -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@canary"></script> -->
<video id="video"></video>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
      video.play();
  });
  }
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = 'https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8';
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
      video.play();
    });
  }
</script>
```

Full documentation given [here](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/).

Also there is a brief description which I would like to share about m3u8 files.
[M3U8 File](https://www.lifewire.com/m3u8-file-2621956)